# ASP.NET Core MVC connect to authenticated SignalR

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr, asp.net-core-webapi

I've got two stand alone projects which both use identity server for mutual authentication.

- I've got an ASP.NET Core Web API project which is setup to understand bearer tokens.
- I've got an ASP.NET Core MVC app which uses cookie auth

I've hosted a web socket in the Web API project and added `[Authorize]` attribute to it.

This is where my problems begins: the ASP.NET Core MVC client is using SignalR JavaScript to make the connection. It therefore is sending a cookie rather than a JWT.

How can I get a JWT token from the cookie and send it? Can I?

Comment: Before you want to get the token from the cookie, how do you add the token to the cookie in your project? From your description, it seems to be two separate project with different authentication.